# How to select first item of DropDownList if value I'm passing to it in FormView BindItem is not in range?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.5

I'm using FormView in Asp.net 4.5 to edit entity model like this:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ....>
   <EditItemTemplate>
     .....
     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# BindItem.value %>'>
     </asp:DropDownList>
     .....
   </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

If BindItem.value is one of the values in DropDownList items this works perfectly, but if BindItem.value was ,for example, null or any value out of range, this will raise an exception like this:

> Selection out of range
>     Parameter name: value

Is there a way to let DropDownList selects first item if BindItem.value is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely one of the things that always bothered me in ASP.NET.  The databinding to drop down lists is not very smart.

I often solved this issue by hand instead of using one/two-way databinding.  In Page_PreRender, you can just manually check if the collection contains the value.  If not, select index 0.  NOTE, you may have to data bind first.

```
private void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (formview1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = formview1.FindControl("dropdownlist1");
        ddl.ClearSelection();
        var item = ddl.FindByValue("[MYVALUE]");
        if (item == null) ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
        else item.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

You can also try this approach (it may be cleaner):

```
protected void dropdown_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    ddl.ClearSelection();
    var item = ddl.FindByValue("[MYVALUE]");
    if (item == null) ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
    else item.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanx but I was looking for another way to do it.